# Error while trying to start vsftpd server

Tags: ftp, fedora, vsftpd

I installed ftp server vsftpd in my fedora 16 machine. It worked fine until this morning. Suddenly, this morning, when i entered command to restart vsftpd it shows following error

```
[root@localhost bibeknam]# service vsftpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  vsftpd.service
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
```

The status report is as follows

```
[root@localhost bibeknam]# service vsftpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  vsftpd.service
vsftpd.service - Vsftpd ftp daemon
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled)
      Active: failed since Wed, 27 Feb 2013 16:37:11 +0545; 8min ago
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vsftpd.service
```

Does any one have solution for this problem?

**Edit 1**: System logs

```
Feb 27 17:01:42 localhost systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 27 17:01:42 localhost systemd[1]: Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: @JennyD : I updated my question

Comment: Does anything get written to the log file /var/log/vsftpd.log?

Comment: In my case it was a SElinux issue. Somehow it doesn't like changing the vsftpd configuration. When disabling SELinux problem was solved. Or you may adjust SElinux accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try below command

```
  $ systemctl enable vsftpd.service

  $ systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

You will probably want to include these lines in your startup scripts

Comment: Amaralkar: both commands did not work :(

Comment: Check this https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=795568

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was installed earlier and removed. 
So configs were available

Setting up vsftpd again with command

`apt-get install vsftpd`   resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting

```
listen_ipv6=YES
```

in /etc/vsftpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering a very old post, but maybe it will help somebody.
I've just installed vsftpd on new Ubuntu 20.04, and it didn't work, almost the same issue, exit code...
I've tried many things, but what is interesting, it is just installed fresh vsftpd which is not working with their own configuration file.
So when I've changed **pam_service_name=vsftpd** to **pam_service_name=ftp**
it started to work.